# Invalid syntax (x= is invalid in function)

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm having trouble with my function/class in Python 3.3.1
This is the code:

```
def snell(ang1=None, ang2=None, v1=None, v2=None, n1=None, n2=None):

    try:
        if ang1==None and n1==None:
            ang1=math.degrees(math.asin((math.sin(ang2)*v1)/v2)
            n1=(n2*v1)/v2
            print("ang1 is equal to:", ang1, sep='\n')
            print("n1 is equal to:", n1, sep='\n')
```

Sorry that the code is separated weirdly, I am very new to this.  In any case, the syntax error I'm getting only says "invalid syntax" and highlights the variable n1 in the line n1=(n2*v1)/v2.  I am wondering what the problem could be, as I see nothing wrong with that snippit of the code.  This is part of a larger section of code, but the rest contains a multitude of elif's in the same format of this if statement.  If any portion of this request is atrociously written please tell me how to improve it...much appreciated.

Comment: Always look on the previous line when you get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing `)` on this line :

```
ang1=math.degrees(math.asin((math.sin(ang2)*v1)/v2))
```